# WebSocket API implementation with EC2 as a backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket, aws-api-gateway, iot

I want to create websocket api using amazon API gateway. Is it possible to configure it such a way that can transfer data from/to EC2 instances? I know with lambda function it is possible but instead of lambda, is it possible to leverage EC2 server a backend for WebSocket API implementation?

Comment: Could you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, it would be AWS service. we will use EC2 as aws service in backend. we dont have HTTP endpoint. there are many documents and tutorials available but 99% of those are using lambda function. I am trying to integrate with EC2.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket API implementation using API Gateway has a integration support for HTTP. So you can expose your HTTP endpoint on EC2 server, then integrate this with your WebSocket API implementation with EC2 as a backend(integration type). For details, refer to below AWS doc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-integration-requests.html

Comment: I' want build a ws server too, but with ec2 without lambda or api gatewaye